# How to bind an infowindow as a property of a marker (google maps API v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Anyone know how to bind an infowindow as a property of a marker?
when I delete a marker, the infowindow goes with it also deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API v3 ~ Simply Close an infowindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946165/google-map-api-v3-simply-close-an-infowindow)

Comment: This question is addressed in: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10346001/1314132

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my way around it was to suppress the built in info windows.  From there I had the click event call a specific window from an array of info windows.  That was my hackish way around making my own info windows without working with the given window.