# How do I clean up an InfoWindow when the associated Marker is hidden?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know that many of us are writing code to open an `InfoWindow` when a marker is clicked. But the `InfoWindow` will stay in place until the upper-right **X** is clicked, which means that setting the associated `Marker`visibility to `false` will create what is essentially an orphaned `InfoWindow`. And there could be multiple `InfoWindow` instances displayed on the Map at the same time. I guess it's simple enough for the user to just click the `InfoWindow` closed, but it feels like hiding the `Marker` should hide the associated `InfoWindow`.

I have started writing code like the following to deal with this scenario:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "click", function() {
    var bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: buildBubbleContent( param1, param2 )
    });
    bubble.open( map, marker );
    //pretty standard stuff to here, but the next line is new (for me):
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( marker, "visible_changed", function() {
        bubble.close();
    });
});
```

Is this what everyone else is doing? It feels like a design pattern that should be called a *ListenBack*. I've never seen the issue addressed in the Google Maps docs. I can't help but think that there must be a simpler mechanism built into the `InfoWindow` to take care of this automatically. Is there a standard way to do this that I have just missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm marking this question as answered, because I have continued scouring the docs and looking at many code samples, but haven't found any other solutions. There is certainly no facility provided with the InfoWindow to automatically remove it from the map when the associated marker is turned off. If anyone finds a better option later, I will happily mark their solution as the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

For a single infoWindow I always create it as a global during map initialization.  My click event starts with:

```
if(infoWindow != null){
   infoWindow.close();
}
infoWindow.setPosition(mouseEvent.latLng);
infoWindow.setContent("....");
// etc
```

Comment: This is a great idea and it ensures that only one InfoWindow is ever displayed. I like the approach, but the requirements for my map say that users shall be able to open multiple InfoWindows. Our users open multiple InfoWindows to get an ad-hoc overview of an area or open more than one to compare the data associated with the markers. Most importantly, this doesn't address the question of how to close the InfoWindow if its associated marker's display is turned off.