# How can I remove an InfoWindow when the Marker is removed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Maps div and list of check boxes that I use to filter markers on the map.

But if I click on a marker, open an `InfoWindow`, and then click on a check box to remove the markers of that type, the `InfoWindow` is not removed from the map.

After I remove the markers, I call this code but the `InfoWindow` stays:

```
try {
    if( infowindow ) {
          infowindow.close();
    }
}
catch(err) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function closeInfoWindow() {
        if (infoWindow !== null) {
            google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(infoWindow);  // just in case handlers continue to stick around
            infoWindow.close();
            infoWindow = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get error in browser: Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined

Comment: Try changing infoWindow in the answer to infowindow and make sure your infowindow var is global.

Comment: you dont use the exact same code as it is.. from the error it is obvious it cant find the infoWindow so either pass it in as a paramter or maintain a global variable. Now since you have multiple InfoWindows it probably makes sense to pass it as a paramter

Comment: Your code might not working because of strict comaprision. `null === undefined` is false but `null == undefined` is true. The last one is recommended for comaprision against undefined/null values.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you change the code that creates the `Marker` click listener that opens your InfoWindow by adding code similar to the following example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "click", function() {
    var bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: buildBubbleContent( param1, param2 )
    });
    bubble.open( map, marker );
    //pretty standard stuff to here, but the next line is new (for me):
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( marker, "visible_changed", function() {
        bubble.close();
    });
});
```

As discussed in question: [How do I clean up an InfoWindow when the associated Marker is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10346001/1314132):