# How to delete an infowindow bound with a marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I wrote a chunk of Google Maps API code follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947371/784005) idea.

But, when I delete all markers, the infowindows bound to these markers are not deleted.

Can anyone show me the solution?

Thanks.

This is how I delete the markers:

```
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

`markersArray` is a global var which stores all the markers.

I declared the infowindows like this:

```
marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        {
            content: '<div>something here</div>'
        });
```

Comment: How do you 'delete' a marker?

Comment: i edited, can u see what's wrong

Answer (score 4):

can't you just delete them along with the markers?

```
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].infoWindow.setMap(null);
      markersArray[i].infoWindow = null; //this one is not necessary I think nut won't hurt
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I found that setting the infoWindow to `null` was necessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's really being deleted, just the map property on the marker is being set to null.  If you really want to delete the markers, you could use the [delete operator](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

```
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing them from the array
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    var arrayLength = markersArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      delete markersArray[i];
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the developers at Mozilla on the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) will do something similar to setting each marker instance to null. The article duncan cited also refers to this.

Therefore having an infoWindow array and setting them to null should do the trick. Another interesting thing which might affect you that has to do with memory management is that

> JavaScript values are allocated when things (objects, strings, etc.) are created and "automatically" free'd when they are not used anymore. The latter process is called garbage collection. This "automatically" is a source of confusion and gives JavaScript (and high-level languages) developers the impression they can decide not to care about memory management. This is a mistake.

-[Developers at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Memory_Management)

So if you're looking for memory management of infoWindows you can take advantage of the "garbage collection" javascript does when it delete variables at the end of functions.