# Creating a custom close button for a Google Maps InfoBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a custom close button for my InfoBox windows, **without** using the built in functionality (I have one InfoBox that doesn't need a close button, which is why I need this work around).

Usually I would do something like this to close a marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
    aMarker.close(map, marker);
});
```

But doing something similar with an element within the InfoBox doesn't work, like so:

```
var closeInfoBox = document.getElementById("close-button");
google.maps.event.addListener(closeInfoBox, 'click', function(){
    aMarker.close(map, marker);
});
```

Is there a way to close an InfoBox using an element within the InfoBox itself?

Edit: no event handlers can be called from within the InfoBox at all it seems. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API v3 ~ Simply Close an infowindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946165/google-map-api-v3-simply-close-an-infowindow)

Comment: Hey I can flick you a working demo - so on click you are expecting a custom dialog box and then you can click on add marker and it will add the marker? let me know if that what you are looking for, `:)`

Comment: @ManseUK: Not a duplicate, that thread is using Google Maps' InfoWindow functionality, whereas I'm using the InfoBox utility.

Comment: @Tats_innit: Thanks for the offer but it doesn't sound like the functionality I need!

Comment: @mmmoustache its the same thing - you need to create an array to keep track of the infoboxes and then call the `close` method on them. See [the api docs here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try addDomListener instead of addListener.
Ex:

```
 var closeInfoBox = document.getElementById("close-button");
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeInfoBox, 'click', function(){
     aMarker.close(map, marker);
 });
```

Comment: Doesn't work either! No event handlers can be called from within the InfoBox for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's quite old question, but since it is popular in search engine I will try to answer.

If you want to hide InfoBox standard close button simply add this stylesheet:

```
.infoBox > img { display: none; }
```

Then create some listener to identify your current InfoBox as @ManseUk mentioned and call `close` method.