# google map - close infowindow when click on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I'm struggling with the close action for my infowindows in my rails app.

my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var raw_markers = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;

    function createSidebarLi(json){
      return json.sidebar;
      //return ("<li>" + json.titre + ' ' + json.address + "</li>");
    };

    function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
      $li.on('click', function(){
        handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
        marker.panTo();
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
      });
    };

    function bindLiToMarkerMouseOver($li, marker){
      $li.on('mouseover', function(){
        handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
        marker.panTo();
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        //marker.serviceObject.setIcon("/assets/marker_sprite.png");
      });
    };

    function createSidebar(json_array){
      _.each(json_array, function(json){
        var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
        $li.appendTo('#markers_list');
        bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
        bindLiToMarkerMouseOver($li, json.marker);
      });
    };

    //handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){

      var markers = handler.addMarkers(raw_markers);

      _.each(raw_markers, function(json, index){
        var marker = markers[index];
        json.marker = marker;
        //google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'mouseover', function(){
          //google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        //});
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
        closeInfoWindow();
      });


      createSidebar(raw_markers);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });

  });

</script>
```

I'm calling the gmap event to close them if the user click on the map but it doesn't work.
I think i have to change where i put the call but i'm not sure, i tried everywhere.

Somebody has an idea ?

ps: I'm using Gmaps4rails but it has nothing to do with the js normally.

Comment: I'm not seeing a function called closeInfoWindow in your code.

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
        closeInfoWindow();
      }); at the end of the script

Comment: OK so what that does is tie the function to the click event of a map.  The function calls closeInfoWindow.  However I don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: this: //google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'mouseover', function(){
          //google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        //}); works well and its not defined neither.  Where should i define it ? Thx for your help.

Comment: Not sure where your infowindows are being opened either.  Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946165/google-map-api-v3-simply-close-an-infowindow) can help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the function:

```
function closeInfoWindow(handler){
  if(handler.currentInfowindow()) {
    handler.currentInfowindow().close();
  }
}
```

and call it:

```
closeInfoWindow(handler);
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I think my listener does not work neither. google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.serviceObject, 'click', function(){ 
        closeInfoWindow(handler);
      });  Is that correct ?

Comment: map object is accessible through, `handler.getMap()`, please read the doc