# Google maps v3 Infowindow doesn't close correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Im working on a custom map (based on gmap3).

Everything works fine except closing Infowindow.
When i click on 'x' button at infowindow popup it... removes? hides? its context, popup and 'x' button slides to marker and it disappears.
Screen: http://prntscr.com/9v37f3

I'm closing infowindow like this:

- close-iw is my custom 'x' button, but after clicking it infowindow behaves in the same way
- infoWindows - array of existing infowindows

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '#close-iw', function(){

    if (infoWindows.length > 0) {

        var openedIw = infoWindows[0];

        openedIw.close();
        infoWindows.splice(0, 1);

    }

});
```

Has anyone seen problem like this? Any solutions?

Comment: perhaps this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946165/google-map-api-v3-simply-close-an-infowindow

Comment: What's the contents of `infoWindows`?  Show us how you populate that.